# How to create an offline repository for debian non-free?

Tags: linux, debian, package

I am using debian squeeze and want to create an offline repository or a cd/dvd for the debian non-free branch. I looked around the internet and all i found out is that there are neither iso images nor there are jidgo files for creating such image so I had the idea to fetch the packages from one of the debian package servers using:

```
 wget -r --no-parent -nH -A*all.deb,*any.deb,*i386.deb \
 ftp://debian.oregonstate.edu/debian/pool/non-free/
```

I know that that I must use file: in my `*/etc/apt/sources.list*` to indicate local repositories but how do I actually create one so that apt or aptitude understands this?

Comment: I suggest reading Debian's documentation about setting up your own apt repo: http://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository

Comment: Oh thanks didn't see it there apt-ftparchive did solve this for me.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a questioned edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> Update: With a few ugly tricks I was able to extract the needed data from pool and the dist folder.
>
> I used the unzipped `Package.gz` to do this:
>
> ```
> grep '^Package\:.*' Packages|awk '{print $2}' >> Names.lst
> grep '^Version\:.*' Packages|awk '{print $2}' >> Versions.lst
> grep '^Architecture\:.*' Packages|awk '{print $2}' >> Arch.lst
> ```
>
> With `vim` I find and remove the ':' in the file `Versions.lst` and generate a shorter `Content.lst` more easy to parse with bash tools:
>
> ```
> paste Names.lst Versions.lst Arch.lst >> Content.lst
> ```
>
> Now I do this:
>
> ```
> cat content.lst | while read line; \
> do echo "$(echo $line|awk '{print $1}')\
> _$(echo $line|awk '{print $2}')_$(echo $line|awk '{print $3}')";\
> done >> content.lst.tmp && mv content.lst.tmp content.lst
> ```
>
> which generates me the file names in the debian directory I need. When finishing with my downloads using `wget` I find and `rsync` the needed file names. `mv` does not work here because I needed the structure as it is referring to in `Packages.gz`:
>
> ```
> cat content.lst |while read line; \
> do find debian/ -type f -name ${line}.deb -exec \
> rsync -rtpog -cisR {} debian2/ \; ;done 
> rm -r debian && mv debian2 debian
> ```
>
> To receive the complete dists tree structure I used `wget` again:
>
> ```
> wget -c -r --no-parent -nH -A*.bz2,*.gz,Release \
> ftp://debian.oregonstate.edu/debian/dists/squeeze/non-free/binary-i386/
> ```
>
> I think the only thing I have to do now is to create the `Contents.gz` file.
>
> The `Contents.gz` file can easily be created using the `apt-ftparchive` program:
>
> ```
> apt-ftparchive contents > Contents-i386 && gzip -f Contents-i386
> ```